# Version numbers of modular software architectures

Tags: deployment, plugins, versioning

We are just desperately looking for a way to get our software versioning for our new software system correctly and I think we could need some help :)

OK so the situation is, that we are developing a modular test software that is based on a plugin architecture. Each test system in our factory will then run an instance that might be consisting of a different set of plugins. Each plugin has a simple semantic versioning like V.1.2.3 and the Plugin-Framework will at some time only be updated very seldomly.

Now the current idea is to create something like a combined string or hash or something that results from the versions of each local plugin version of that particular instance. That could then for example be mapped with a local version to make that string/hash thing more readable.

So in summary:

- Each module has a semantic version like V.1.2.3
- The local instance of each test software then has e.g. a version defined by a string like "PluginAV1.2.3_PluginBV2.3.4_PluginCV.3.4.5"
- This local version string is then labelled with another alias version such as V.1.0.0 which is only locally valid

Somehow that system seems to work but we are somehow not satisfied.

So I would be very grateful if you could share your ideas or experiences.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the Semver docs? https://semver.org/